# Symfony 4 FindBy() and returning an array via JSON

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following line of code

```
$apps = $appRepositry->findBy(['user' => $user]);
```

I then return the results via JSON using the following

```
$json_data[] = array(
                            "state" => "success",
                            "user_apps" => $apps,
                            "total_registerd_apps" => count($apps),
                            );
```

The issue I have is that the count is correct but the "user_apps" array is returning blank.

```
 {
    state = success;
    "total_registerd_apps" = 1;
    "user_apps" =     (
                {
        }
    );
}
```

I think it is because the FindBy returns objects but I am not sure. Could someone explain how to convert the result to an array that can then be sent via JSON?

Thanks

Comment: You need to have your objects implement the JSONSerializable interface, add a jsonSerialize method to them which returns an array representation of the object and then use json_encode on them: http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php and http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php for examples

Comment: Symfony also has some tools that can help.  Start here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a serializer with groups.

Information about serialization : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Information about serialization groups : 
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups

```
 public function listAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher, Request $request)
{
    //...your code...//
    $yourObjectifiedResult = $appRepositry->findBy(['user' => $user]);
    $yourNormalizedResult = $this->normalizeWithCircularHandler(
                $yourObjectifiedResult,
                ['groups']);
    //Serializer will convert your result from Object to Json Array automatically. To get a specific set of data, you can use groups.
}

public function normalizeWithCircularHandler($data, $displayGroups, $normalizerCallbacks = false)
{
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);

    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });

    if(false != $normalizerCallbacks && is_array($normalizerCallbacks)) {
        $normalizer->setCallbacks($normalizerCallbacks);
    }

    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);

    return $serializer->normalize($data , null, ['groups' => $displayGroups]);
}
```

Comment: I am using circular handler for some reasons. you can use a simple normalizer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a serializer to serialize your data into JSON:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html